# Unclickable links in GTK3 apps

Tags: gnome, configuration, gtk, user-profile

I can't open link in any gtk3 app by left clicking (for example web link in Ubuntu software center or local link in Gnome disks). I am able to do it via right click, then click in submenu "open link".
Couple months ago I've switched from Ubuntu to Xubuntu and hoped this problem to be solved, but it still exists. Surprisingly, if I create new user with clean configuration - clicking links works. Now I want to remove this spoiled config file in my profile directory, but can't find it. What should I delete?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in Gxneur app. It was reading mouse movements. Disabled this option ("Do not track cursor movement") and everything now works fine.